# Passing value (HTTP response) from one component to another: Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-directives, angular2-services

I have a component that's getting a HTTP response on success in 'response' and then navigates to another component. I have assigned the value at the first component in 'pushKey'. Now I want 'pushKey' to be accessible from the second component where I have a form where I want to pass the value of 'pushKey' as a hidden input. What should I do for that?

Here is my first component:

```ts
@Component({
template:'
...
<input type="file" id="sampleFile">
<button (click)="submit()">Submit</button>
...
'
 })
        export class FirstComponent{

        constructor(public uploaderService: Uploader, private _router: Router) { }

        public pushKey: String;

        submit() {

let uploadFile = (<HTMLInputElement>window.document.getElementById('sampleFile')).files[0];

        let myUploadItem = new MyUploadItem(uploadFile);

        this.uploaderService.onSuccessUpload = (item, response, status, headers) => {
                    // success callback
                    this.pushKey = response.toString();
                    console.log('Push Key:'+ response.toString())
                    this._router.navigate(['second-component']);
                };
        }
    }
```

In my second component:

```ts
@Component({
template:'
...
<input type="hidden" name="pushKey" value="pushKey">
...
'
})

export class SecondComponent{

//what should I do here to get the value of pushKey from the first component?

}
```

Here's my service:

```ts
import { Injectable }  from '@angular/core';
import { UploadItem }  from './upload-item';

@Injectable()
export class Uploader {
    onProgressUpload = (item: UploadItem, progress: number) => {};
    onCompleteUpload = (item: UploadItem, response: any, status: any, headers: any) => {};
    onSuccessUpload = (item: UploadItem, response: any, status: any, headers: any) => {};
    onErrorUpload = (item: UploadItem, response: any, status: any, headers: any) => {};
    onCancelUpload = (item: UploadItem, response: any, status: any, headers: any) => {};

    constructor() { }

    upload(item: UploadItem) {
        if(this.isHTML5()) {
            this.xhrTransport(item);
        } else {
            this.onErrorUpload(item, 'Unsupported browser.', null, null);
        }
    }

    private isHTML5(): boolean {
        return !!((<any>window).File && (<any>window).FormData);
    }

    private xhrTransport(item: UploadItem) {
        let xhr  = new (<any>window).XMLHttpRequest();
        let form = new (<any>window).FormData();

        this.forEach(item.formData, (key: string, value: any) => {
            form.append(key, value);
        });

        form.append(item.alias, item.file, item.file.name);


        xhr.upload.onprogress = (event: any) => {
            let progress = Math.round(event.lengthComputable ? event.loaded * 100 / event.total : 0);
            this.onProgressUpload(item, progress);
        };

        xhr.onload = () => {
            let headers = this.parseHeaders(xhr.getAllResponseHeaders());
            let response = this.parseResponse(headers['Content-Type'], xhr.response);
            console.log(xhr.response);
            if(this.isSuccessStatus(xhr.status)) {
                this.onSuccessUpload(item, response, xhr.status, headers);
            } else {
                this.onErrorUpload(item, response, xhr.status, headers);
            }
            this.onCompleteUpload(item, response, xhr.status, headers);
        };

        xhr.onerror = () => {
            let headers = this.parseHeaders(xhr.getAllResponseHeaders());
            let response = this.parseResponse(headers['Content-Type'], xhr.response);
            this.onErrorUpload(item, response, xhr.status, headers);
            this.onCompleteUpload(item, response, xhr.status, headers);
        };

        xhr.onabort = () => {
            let headers = this.parseHeaders(xhr.getAllResponseHeaders());
            let response = this.parseResponse(headers['Content-Type'], xhr.response);
            this.onCancelUpload(item, response, xhr.status, headers);
            this.onCompleteUpload(item, response, xhr.status, headers);
        };

        xhr.open(item.method, item.url, true);

        xhr.withCredentials = item.withCredentials;

        this.forEach(item.headers, (name: string, value: string) => {
            xhr.setRequestHeader(name, value);
        });

        xhr.send(form);
    }

    private isSuccessStatus(status: number) {
        return (status >= 200 && status < 300) || status === 304;
    }

    private forEach(obj: any, callback: any) {
        for (var i in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                callback(i, obj[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    private parseHeaders(headers: string) {
        let dict = {};
        let lines = headers.split('\n');
        for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
            let entry = lines[i].split(': ');
            if(entry.length > 1) {
                dict[entry[0]] = entry[1];
            }
        }
        return dict;
    }

    private parseResponse(contentType: string, response: string) {
        let parsed = response;
        if(contentType && contentType.indexOf('application/json') === 0) {
            try {
                parsed = JSON.parse(response);
            } catch(e) {
            }
        }
        return parsed;
    }
}
```

Comment: Move the code to a shared services. See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Comment: Is there nothing I can do with simple input outputs?

Comment: Not if you're using the router to add a component.

Comment: I have this fat arrow function in my first component where I am getting the value of response which is inside another function- submit() which is getting triggered from the first component. Moreover it's a HTTP response which only has a value when the HTTP request is successful. Can I really get the value from a shared service? If it is, then how?

Comment: Just use an observable in the service and subscribe to it from the component. When the observable emits an event, the component receives it. The link above has examples.

Comment: I am getting confused. Should I edit the question and add the service I have currently for you to elaborate a bit?

Comment: Sure, it would be easier if you could demonstrate what you tried and where you failed or where the actual behavior is different of what you expect.

Comment: I have just updated the question and added my service, and also added more detail to my first component. Can you please recheck the question?

Comment: That's way too much code and no information about what you try to accomplish, and what the expected and actual behavior is.

Comment: I have a component where I have a form that's uploading an image using submit() and  getting a key in a HTTP response on success in 'response'. I want my first component to navigate to the second component with the value of response, assigned in 'pushKey', so that I can use 'pushKey' anywhere I want in the second component.

I have assigned the value at the first component in 'pushKey'. I can print the value successfully in the console.